# ggplot draws incorrect plot margins when saving to pdf

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

When I run the following (reproducible) R code, ggplot outputs a plot with incorrect margins (which lie somewhat around the specified 5mm mark).
I've tried ggsave (with different dpi settings), units in inches or npc etc. but nothing seems to work.
My goal is to write a theme which specifies certain margins for all of its plots. But this way any such theme would be completely pointless.

```
    library(tidyverse)
    
    p6 = ggplot(data.frame(x=rnorm(7356,5,3),y=rnorm(7356,4,2))) +
      geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y)) +
      theme(plot.margin = unit(c(5,5,5,5),"mm"),
            axis.text = element_text(),
            axis.title = element_text(),
            plot.background = element_rect(colour="grey",fill="grey"),
            axis.ticks = element_blank())
    
    p7 = ggplot(data.frame(x=rnorm(7356,5,3),y=rnorm(7356,4,2))) +
      geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y)) +
      theme(plot.margin = unit(c(5,5,5,5),"mm"),
            axis.text = element_blank(),
            axis.title = element_blank(),
            plot.background = element_rect(colour="grey",fill="grey"),
            axis.ticks = element_blank())
    pdf("C:\\themetest2.pdf", paper="a4", width = 6.6929134, height=7,colormodel = "cmyk")
    
    p6
    p7
    
    dev.off()
```

Even worse, the error changes if axis.text or axis.title changes:

[with axis.title and axis.text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5Xgm.png)

[without axis.title and axis.text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fHlx.png)

How can I output my ggplot to pdf with the exact measurements specified?

Comment: have you tried using the `ggsave()` function instead? I was able to get a pdf of p6 with the following code: `ggsave(filename = "themetest2.pdf", p6, width = 6.6929134, height = 7, units = "cm")`

Comment: I did. But the output pdf had the same faulty margins (and it was much harder to measure them as the pdf ended with the plot instead of the a4 page). I also tried the Cairo PdF device but with the same result.

Comment: I always have a hard time remembering which things add space to the plot. For example, I think axis ticks still have "length" even though they aren't there. See how the second plot looks if you add `axis.ticks.length = unit(0, "mm")`

Comment: Your measurements seem to assume that the margin starts where the ink of the letters end. The lineheight of text is not just the x-height, but allows for text ascension and descension as well, making the total area of whitespace larger than the margin alone.

Comment: I will test axis.tick.length = 0 tomorrow. Unfortunately I assume this won't solve the problem since I remember encoutering a version of this were the margin became smaller.

Comment: Yes, I measured from ink to ink but that can't be the root of the problem because it would imply that the error doesn't change between plots (as the text size stays consistent) (I have tested this with explicit size arguments aswell).

Answer (score 1):

So this seems to be unsolvable by conventional means as ggplot can't be convinced to draw exact absolute plot margins. But there is a very powerful though hacky solution: Append an object of your own class to your plot and create a ggplot_add.[class_name] function which then can take the plot and draw it without margins onto another plot using ggdraw and drawplot. Inside drawplot just adjust the margins depending on the size of the graphics device (dev.size is useful here)!

Looks something like this:

```
append_object_of_new_class = function(){
  out = theme_void()
  class(out) = c("new_class", "theme","gg")
  return(out)
}

ggplot_add.new_class = function (object,plot,object_name){
  devdim = dev.size()
  background = ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0,1),y=c(0,1))) +
    geom_blank() +
    theme_void() +
    theme(plot.background = element_rect(),
          plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0),"mm"))
    plot = ggdraw() +
        draw_plot(background) +
        draw_plot(plot,x=[your margins calculated from devdim],
                       y=[your margins calculated from devdim],
                       width=[your margins calculated from devdim],
                       height=[your margins calculated from devdim])
}
```